# django MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL TEMPLATES

Tags: python, django

the model looks like

```
class Cars(models.Model):
    name = models.CharFidle(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5,decimal_places=2)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/cars')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

the settings

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

but when I use the it in the templates like this

```
{% for car in cars %}
        <li>{{ car.name }}</li>
        <li>{{ car.price }}</li>
        <a>{{ car.photo }}</a>
        <img src="{{ car.photo.url }}"/>
    {% endfor %}
```

I can't get the image, what's the matter?

It  would be wonderful anyone help me

Comment: if you inspect the element in the resulting HTML, what is placed inside the SRC attribute of the image?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/cars/38898.jpg looks like this, but [22/Nov/2014 20:29:44] "GET /media/images/cars/38898.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2191

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that could be going on here:

1. You're running a non-development web server that hasn't been setup to serve static media. The solution here will vary depending on what web server you're running.
2. You're running the development web server and haven't setup [static serving](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development). For this, I'd add the following to your root urls.py file:

> ```
>   urlpatterns = [
>       # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
>   ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
> ```

3. There's a permissions issue in your MEDIA_ROOT directory. In this case, I'd make sure your MEDIA_ROOT directory is readable by your web server.

Comment: What about: urlpatterns = [ ... ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: succeed !I have add the urlpattern in the wrong place

Comment: well, I edit it in a app url.py, not in the root url.py.

Answer (score 1):

From your settings.py I assume you have made a media folder in your base directory. If u had then you are going right. I assume the problem is in your template.

Try this:

```
<img src="/static/{{car.photo}}" width="100" height="100" />
```

Dont forget to include `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top of the template after extending the base.. You are ready to go...

Comment: I make a mistake in the urls.py , thanks all the same

Comment: sorry my repution was not enough~

Answer (score 1):

```
urlpatterns = [
  # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ..
  ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

add this to my root urls.py, and remeber in the **root urls.py**